# Tortoise SVN - Can't connect to SVN "target machine activity refused it"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm on a network at a major bank and I'm trying to connect to a SVN repository from my Windows 7 machine.  I'm using the latest version of Tortoise (as of yesterday) 64 bit client.

When I try and connect using repo-browser, I am able to log in with my credentials, but I then get the error, "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Other people in my network are able to connect to the repository.  Someone else out out of the network was able to log on to the repository using my credentials.  I also tried to use superuser credentials to log on and got the same error.

I disabled my virus protection software and still got the same results.

I tried accessing from the command line and still got the same results.

I'm sure it's the way my machine or my network is configured, but I am not a network person, so I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Kick it to your network team to figure out. It's not a Subversion issue, it's networking. Just don't tell them that someone who isn't you and isn't inside your network has your credentials - that's a serious offense in the financial institution I used to work in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a proxy issue. I entered in the right proxy information and voila! I was granted access.

Comment: OK, you found the answer, and it sounds exactly like my problem.  Where is this proxy setting, and how do I set it, please?

Comment: Right click on your application and see if you can find the settings.

Comment: "On my application?"  *my*?  My application is a compiler I'm building.  Why would there be "proxy" information associated with it? You mean on its binary?  On its sources?  You mean using the file explorer?   Internet explorer?  Please, be explicit and detailed.  What is obvious to you, is not necessarily obvious to others.

Comment: When I meant my application, I meant TortoiseSVn.  I don't have it installed on my current work or home computer, but I meant rick click on the actual application.  That's the best I can recall.  Sorry.

Comment: For further followers: Kristy apparently means "(mouseon) TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Network " which provides a means to configure a proxy server.  For what it worth, my problem was different and stupid (story of most of my life): I misconfigured the HOSTS file and lied about the IP address of the machine holding the SVN server.  That just doesn't work.  Fixed the IP address, suddenly... sunlight.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but something for people to consider as well; make sure that whatever webserver you are running is actually running.  That may sound obvious, but I was using VisualSVN (which basically has its own Apache webserver built in) and it had stopped the service after a reboot.  Check this first before messing about with proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

Check The proxy definitions in the servers file located at `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`.

I removed the Proxy lines:

```
ssl-trust-default-ca  = no
http-proxy-host = 
http-proxy-username = 
http-proxy-password =
```

And it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Redmine, your URL for the repository is wrong. You will need to use the URL that can be found in the Project in Settings->Repositories. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What software is this screen shot from? Not Tortoise SVN, which is the only thing mentioned by the op? For most people this answer will be useless.

Comment: Im using Redime. Thanks for the note :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case when you copy URL from server repository it contains localhost path.
something like `http://xxxx-xxx-xx-xx:portnumber/svn/MyRepository/`
if you install SVN on server and try above path then it will show the required output, i.e. folder structure of your repository.

But when you try to access it form remote computer you need to replace all the things after `http://` and before port number colon by your sever IP.

It will look like `http://myserverip:myport/svn/MyRepository/`

Also check windows firewall port is opened or not which you are accessing.

Answer (score -1):

this fixed with relocating to the right branch

TortiseSVN >>relocate then put ur correct URL